# Is there a Sixth Man of the Year Award equivalent in other sports?

Tags: basketball, nba, awards

The [Sixth Man of the Year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NBA_Sixth_Man_of_the_Year_Award) is an award in the US NBA, to the player performing best for their team coming into play as a substitute. Players are eligible if they play in more games as a substitute than as a starting player.

Does an equivalent or similar award exist in any other sport or competition? These are preferably for major sports and in major competitions.

Comment: Basketball seems predisposed to this because substitutes play significant time and might be less likely to move into the starting role due to only 5 starters. In american football, the starters usually play the full game, and changes tend to only be made for injury or situationally for certain formations. In hockey, players constantly rotate (not sure the starting line is even necessarily supposed to be the best). In soccer subs are important but also limited, such that a players don't equal opportunity. Baseball would probably be the best equivalence, but even then, it's very situational.

Answer (score 1):

There is no award with the same amount of prestige given to a bench player. This is because in most other sports, the starters are in for the whole game, like in football or baseball.

The closest thing is the Major League Baseball Reliever of the Year award in baseball. Because they both kind of mean which player had the biggest impact on a team even though they didn't start.

Source: [Baseball Almanac](http://www.baseball-almanac.com/awards/aw_snfi.shtml)